# Determine the elements of the set $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} :( \exists x,y \in \mathbb{N} )(n = 2x+3y) \}.$

Tags: real-analysis, induction, natural-numbers

I let $n=1-9$ and solved for $x$ and $y$ to find the elements of the set. When $n=1-4$, you can't find an $x$ or $y$ to make the equality true. When $n=5$, it is true that $x=y=1$. But then, when $n=6$ you can't find two natural numbers that make it true. When $n$ is greater than or equal to $7$ though, you can find two natural numbers $x$ and $y$ to make it true. So I said my set was, $\{ n \in \mathbb{N}|n>6 \}$ but I think I have to include that $n=5$ as well as it is also true, but not quite sure how to include that. 
I have to prove this using induction but I've gotten stuck after multiple attempts. Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: First, consider that all even numbers>6 are easy to generate ($x=\frac{n-6}2,\;y=2$). All odd numbers greater than 5 also are easy to generate ($x=\frac{n-3}2,\;y=1$).

Comment: **Hint** $\ $  Base cases $2,3\in S.\,$  Induction: $\, n\in S\,\Rightarrow n+2\in S\,$ by $\,x\to x+1\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque there is of course the problem of whether $0\in\mathbb N$. The question seems to imply that that is not the case here.

Comment: @Parcly But the same idea works, just choose the correct base cases

Comment: @BillDubuque I know, right?